# Unit tests with chai and Eshint are not passing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jshint

Hope you can help, recently moved from jshint to eslint and Im looking to see how to get my tests to pass wihtout making changes;

Take for exmaple the following test

```
expect(ctrl.screens).to.not.be.undefined;
```

eshint complains with the following expection;

```
error  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

Changing the test to;

```
expect(ctrl.screens).to.not.be.undefined();
```

Gives the following error:

```
TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a function (evaluating 'expect(ctrl.screens).to.not.be.undefined()')
```

Any ideas what approach to take here? All the tests pass when I remove eshint from the task list so  I need for some way to clean up these tests.

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing for undefined is tricky. There are some alternative ways to do it. I normally check for `typeof(variable) === 'undefined`.

Example:

```
expect(typeof(ctrl.screens)).to.not.equal('undefined');
```

Comment: @user falsy doesn't guarantee that it is undefined. It can be either null, false, undefined, an empty string, etc...

Comment: @fmsf This answer works, but not because the original check for undefined (i.e. `expect(ctrl.screens).to.not.be.undefined;`) was invalid. It works because it uses a function call, which passes the eshint rule.